# Update value of a column c# winforms applicaiton

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to update a column value with a where clause but it triggers an error

> "Must declare the scalar variable "@datestring"

My problematical part of the application is this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value = "";
            string connetionString = "Data Source=LENOVO-PC\\CDVI_CENTAUR;Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = null;

            value = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            var datestring = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            var FirstName = value.Split(' ')[0];
            var LastName = value.Split(' ')[1];
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cnn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    cnn.Open();
                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE [Centaur3Main].[dbo].[Users]  SET [UDText12b] = @datestring WHERE FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName ", cnn))
                    {
                        // Create and set the parameters values 
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FirstName;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LastName;


                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }

            }
```

The value of the datestring is from a datetimepicker and it has a value. So I don't understand how to fix this error.`
Can you please help me. I know it is a newbie caused error but I cannot figure it out. /I'm still a junior by the way/. Tried different things and solutions from the internet but still cannot figure the solution workaround.
Can you please give me a solution about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are not passing any parameter for `@datestring` as the error clearly says. You need to pass that parameter as well like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@datestring", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datestring;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add one more parameter to your SQL command. This parameter is **@datestring**. Try like:

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE [Centaur3Main].[dbo].[Users]  SET [UDText12b] = @datestring WHERE FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName ", cnn))
{
  // Create and set the parameters values 
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FirstName;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LastName;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@datestring",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```